# Copy comments with T4 template

Tags: templates, t4, xml-comments

I'm generating a class from an interface using T4 templates, and I want to be able to copy xml-comments from the interface to the class methods. Is it possible and if yes, how?

In my template I am just taking the interface methods and copying them like this:

```
foreach(var m in typeof(IFrontEndService).GetMethods()) 
{
      <#= "Some output here"; #>
}
```

Comment: There are multiple ways to do what you are asking, but it's not clear what you are doing now and why it's not meeting your needs.  Can you provide a sample of the T4 code you are using now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, I'm not aware of any existing public API for reading xmldoc comments.  You're pretty much stuck reading the comments out of the XML file on disk.  Unfortunately, mapping the member names to the identifiers used in the XML file is non-trivial.  I use a variation on the approach described at http://www.binarycoder.net/fxcop/html/doccomments.html.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be using [CodeModel](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/envdte.codeinterface.comment.aspx). Here is an example of using this API in a T4 template: http://www.olegsych.com/2007/12/how-to-use-t4-to-generate-decorator-classes/

Comment: I don't see it copying any comments across. It is using Reflection, which has no comments.